# Error in listing all blobs under the container in for loop statement- The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server

Tags: python, azure, containers, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I am trying to list blobs in a Blob Container in Azure storage account. Here is my code:

```
 blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(landing_Access_token)
 container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
 blob_list = container_client.list_blobs(prefix='/crm365/internal/reference/')
 
 for i in blob_list:
 print(i.name)
```

I got the error : `The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server` when I did the for loop to get every name of blobs. Everthing befor the loop was OK.

I have passed the prefix in list_blobs, but It was still same
I've checked the connection string and I was able to log in the Azure storage and upload blobs to in the container. Could someone kindly help with that?

Comment: You need to use `blob_list = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with='/crm365/internal/reference/') `  refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-containerclient-list-blobs

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I 've tried this, but it has the same error

Comment: Check the below answer, Hope it will address your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code below to list the blobs with specified prefixes using Python.

In my environment, I have some files with the below structure.

**Portal:**

[image]
**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

connection_string = "xxxxx"
container_name = "sample"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_list = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with='backup/backup2/backup3')
for i in blob_list:
    print(i.name.split('/')[-1])
```

**Output:**

```
state_county_codes.xlsm
states_and_counties.xlsx
temp.png
temp2.jpg
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[azure.storage.blob.ContainerClient class | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-containerclient-list-blobs)